# if L is CF does that mean L interaction L reverse is also CF?

Tags: automata

if L is CF does that mean L interaction L reverse is also CF? thats the whole question since CF is clsoed for reverse it makes sense but there are alot of refute out there for interactions, so I was wondering how can i prove it ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to define what you mean by "interaction" and by "CF".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i refuted it for example take L={a^i b^i a^j | i, j >=0}
means L^R = L={a^j b^i a^i | i, j >=0}
which leads us to L interaction L^R = {a^n b^n a^n | n>= 0 } which is clearly not an CFL

Comment: (There's *inter**se**ction*.)